# Get Taxonomy Permalink with ACF object ID

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

Ok this is what i need, i need to echo the permalink of a custom taxonomy archive page on wp. I can get the object ID but i can't find a way to use that same id to get the taxonomy permalink.

This is an example of my code:

```
<?php 
    get_field('services_1', $id);
    // this returns the id of the taxonomy which is 22
    // i tried to saved it into a variable like so:
    $term = get_field('services_1', $id);
    echo get_term_link( $term, 'type-of-services' ); ?>
?>
```

This didn't work and i just give up trying, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use [wp_list_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'your_taxonomy',
    'title_li' =>'',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'parent' => 0
);

<ul> wp_list_categories($args); </ul>
```

Comment: Yes thanks, im using Advanced Custom Fields so my client can change the information from the front end, i can get that info with the acf get_field() function.

I need the value (which is an id) and pass it to a wordpress function get_term_link();

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to start first with verifying if the values you are passing to the function `get_term_link` are correct. If you go to wp-admin > Taxonomy terms listing page > edit the particular term in your example > the page URL should be in this format:

```
http://<root>/wp-admin/edit-tags.php??action=edit&taxonomy=<taxonomy_name>&tag_ID=<term_id>&post_type=<post_type>
```

Then check if `<taxonomy_name>` and `<term_id>` match the ones in your example ('type-of-services' and 22).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah i've checked it. It is 22.

Comment: How about the taxonomy name? Can you try hardcoding the parameter values like `echo get_term_link(22, 'type-of-services');` and see if it will print something?

Comment: Yeah it does, as i mention before. I can get the result by hardcoding the 22 but this isn't dynamic. My client won't be able to update that information from the frontend.

Comment: I understand, I just asked to verify if the hardcoded sample values will give the expected result. Since it is, your issue must be something to do with the value being returned by this line: `$term = get_field('services_1', $id);`

Comment: Yep hardcoding give me the desire results. Didn't know how to solve it. I'll keep digging, meanwhile i hardcode it. Thanks.